# How to include a C/C++ lib (e.g. libcurl) in a C++ project (IDE: Eclipse)?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I have a problem, I'm working on a C++ project (I'm using Eclipse as my IDE).

Now I want to make use of a C/C++ library, for example libcurl, so I download curl and don't know what to do next.

Must I only include the .h and .c files I need or must I compile it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to use a library (this, of course might differ from library to library) is to include all of the header files from the library, include them as needed, use functions that they provide. Then, when building the application, link the objects with the library object (.a, .lib, whatever the extension). If you don't have the .a or .lib file, then you should build that independently

Comment: If I have .a or .lib file how can I use it in Eclipse Project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896260/how-to-attach-library-to-the-android-project-and-use-it)

Comment: In your `Project Properties`, in the `C/C++ Build Settings`, in the `Linker Libraries` section, Add your paths to where the .lib or .a files are kept to the search path area. Add the specific files you want to link with to the libraries area.

Answer (score 0):

You must compile it before, then include the h files in your include path (in the Eclipse project).  You will also need to find out how to import the library that you compile into your Eclipse project.

Once all that is done, you can make calls to the library after #include'ing the appropriate headers.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are possible. Compiling to a library is probably easier.