# How to attach library to the Android project and use it?

Tags: android, reference, attachment

I have a problem I have a `.so` file written on `C`. I want to attach this file to a Android Project ! I am using **Eclipse** ...

**Who can tell how I can attach .so file to my android project ?**

**EDITED:**

**I can't understand how I can import library (.so) to the eclipse project using NDK AS told in comments of user: mudit ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a C library or for that any native library, you have to use Android NDK.

For more details on Android NDK: check [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).

For downloading the Android NDK: check [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: And how I can import .libs to project using NDK and Eclipse ? Can I ?

Comment: To use these libs, you need to put these in your source code and then you need to compile the code using NDK and some stuff. I would suggest, please read the documentation provided with NDK, it will tell you what to do plus there are some samples that come along with NDK. you can start your research with those samples.

Comment: And I can do it using eclipse ? yes ?

Comment: For compiling the native code, first you need to install cygwin if you are a windows user; for linux and mac users you can use default shell. And once you are done compiling the native code, you can further development is eclipse

Comment: Let Imagen that I have created mylib.so library ... Now How I can attach it to eclipse project ?